# Apache file does not exist with MAMP 2.1.1

Tags: apache, mamp

I recently had to reinstall MAMP which never gave me any problems before but since then I've had problems with files not showing up and being unable to write to them. I then opened MAMP Pro and changed the permissions of my htdocs folder but I continue to have problems with files disappering on my localhost.

I checked the Apache log and and found this message repeated for everything I open or try to open:

[client ::1] File does not exist

My Apache is running on Port 8888 as it always has as there is apparently a conflict with my native Mac server (I'm on Mountain Lion) if I change it to 80.

I read something about the DocumentRoot not being in httpd.config but I'm afraid to touch that as I don't know what I'm doing.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem it was due to an earlier restoration of the backup from time machine. The file indeed did not exist as it had been replaced but the path was still in existance. Hope this helps someone.